# ALT+Tab does not show all open windows

Tags: 21.10

Since i upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10, when i press ALT+TAB to switch the window with focus, it does not show all open windows. I have 2 monitors.
I already made apt update e apt upgrade and reboot the computer but the problem remains. I did not find a reason for missing some windows.
When i press ALT it shows all open windows but the same missing windows appear in a second box in the top:
[image]
On the dock menu,all windows appear open (and this is currently the way i can go to the missing open window).

Any clues to fix this?
Thank you.

I made a screen video to show the problem:
[screencast video of possible ubuntu error](https://youtu.be/CMqY9fkADZg)

Comment: Sorry, ALT+TAB. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try win+tab, good luck!

Comment: Yes! This works!